# How to Add Navigation View in Fragment in android?

Tags: android

I have a Fragment named as DealMailListig and have Main Activity .I am trying to add a navigation view in my Fragment not in Main Activity with drawer toggle Icon .But do not get success .pls guide me for that .

any help will be appreciate.

here is my code of Deal MainListing
:-

```
public class CDealMainListing extends Fragment {
// --Commented out by Inspection (11-04-2016 10:45):public LinearLayout m_MainLayout;
private ViewPager m_ViewPager;// declare view pager variable
private View m_Main;// declare View Main variable

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deals_main_screen, container, false);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show(); // show tool bar
    init();// initlize controls
    return m_Main;
}

private void init() {
    TabLayout m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Deals"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));// add stories tab
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab

    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    CDealMainListingPager m_oDealMainScreenPager = new CDealMainListingPager
            (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oDealMainScreenPager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create an activity and in this activity you will have to create the navidation view and the tab layout. Then you'll need an adapter (ViewPagerAdapter) and call fragment manager like this :

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Then you'll have to add fragment to your adapter like this :

```
adapter.addFragment(new WhateverFragment(), 'title');
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(the view pager is declared before)

Then you'll have to set up the tabLayout with the viewpager :

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

You can try this and feel free to ask for more detail :)

Comment: I tried this but I dont want to make in activity I want to make in fragment

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible except if you have an activity which extends FragmentActivity